# ROS Indigo installation problem on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was using the tutorial [http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi] to install ROS on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (Raspbian Jessie) to control a robot called Baxter and run Gazebo (Simulation tool for ROS).

Currently, I am having problems in the step where I have to build the catkin packages (Step 3.3 'Building the catkin Workspace' on the tutorial. The problem is that it says:

```
CMake Error at gtest/cmake_install.cmake:42(file):
    file INSTALL cannot find
    "home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/gtest/libgtest.so".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    cmake_install.cmake:154 (include)
```

Can anyone give me some directions to overcome this problem?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266665/ros-indigo-installation-problem-on-raspbian-jessie/) by [jchoi0415](https://answers.ros.org/users/31242/jchoi0415/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-18**:
Please don't use screenshots for what is essentially text. Just copy-paste terminal text into your question and make sure to use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to format it properly.

**Comment by [jchoi0415](https://answers.ros.org/users/31242/jchoi0415/) on 2017-07-18**:
Sorry there, first time using public Q&A forums. Fixed up my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the same issue ... before this error, on warnings the compiler said something about "Target "gtest" has EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL" and I thought that someone is telling to exclude and the error said this lib may be included!!

So for a rapid test I got into the

```
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/test
```

and edited the gtest.cmake

```
sudo nano gtest.cmake
```

Commenting this line (#) to avoid the exclusion of this files:

```
if(ARG_EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
    #set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
endif()
```

and comment too

```
#set_target_properties(gtest gtest_main PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 1)
```

Save the file and try again

After that, the compiler compile the gtest and worked fine

Its not a definitive solution, but works well, it helps!!

Another aproach is to remove the gtest compile, but not tested it yet

Thanks

(PS: in this tutorial they remove the ros_lisp (--exclude roslisp) because the "dependency sbcl is not available in the Raspbian" ... but I have included and the dependency is ok by now!!)

---

Originally posted by [Hobbert Evergreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/28992/hobbert-evergreen/) with karma: 46 on 2017-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Near32](https://answers.ros.org/users/30465/near32/) on 2017-09-25**:
Thank you so much for those tips, it works fine with Raspbian Stretch too, following this tutorial :
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi , in part 3.3

**Comment by [JesperMarkling](https://answers.ros.org/users/34834/jespermarkling/) on 2018-04-26**:
Worked for me.. thank you. Working with _Jessi lite following this http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

**Comment by [ameykasar](https://answers.ros.org/users/37642/ameykasar/) on 2018-09-21**:
Worked for me as well. Working on Stretch on Raspberry Pi 3. Thank you.